# Calculating total presence time from overlapping login intervals

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to create a DAX measure in Power BI to calculate the total man-hours the users were logged into a system. It is possible that users were logged in on multiple workstations at the same time, so the logged-in intervals may overlap.

I have the following test data:
[image]

I have come up with a measure that works in most cases (Name: A, B, E).

```
Man Hours = SUMX(
SUMMARIZE(Logins, Logins[Name], "x",
    var l = Logins
    return 
    CONVERT(
        SUMX(
            FILTER(Logins, 
                var t = [End]
                return COUNTROWS(FILTER(l,  [Start] <= t && t <= [End])) == 1
            ),
            [End]) 
        - SUMX( 
            FILTER(Logins, 
                    var t = [Start]
                    return COUNTROWS(FILTER(l,  [Start] <= t && t <= [End])) == 1
                ), [Start]
            )
        , DOUBLE
    )
), [x]
) * 24
```

It fails when any of the start or end of the users intervals match exactly (e.g. all the sessions of the user were terminated by the system automatic with the same timestamp) (Name: C,D):

In the lower right part of the screen are the expected values of the man-hour subtotals.

[image]

**How can I fix my measure so it can handle these edge cases?**

Answer (score 1):

I have sidestepped the issue by adding 1 second to the start or end of the intervals where the timestamp was matching.

[image]

```
Fudge_start =
VAR same_start =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Logins ),
        [Name] = EARLIER ( Logins[Name] )
            && [Start] = EARLIER ( [Start] )
    )
VAR max_end =
    MAXX ( same_start, [End] )
VAR min_id =
    MINX ( FILTER ( same_start, [End] = max_end ), [Id] )
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTROWS ( same_start ) > 1
            && [End] = max_end
            && [Id] = min_id,
        [Start] - TIME ( 0, 0, 1 ),
        [Start]
    )
```

and

```
Fudge_end =
VAR same_end =
    FILTER (
        ALL ( Logins ),
        [Name] = EARLIER ( Logins[Name] )
            && [End] = EARLIER ( [End] )
    )
VAR max_start =
    MAXX ( same_end, [Start] )
VAR min_id =
    MINX ( FILTER ( same_end, [Start] = max_start ), [Id] )
RETURN
    IF (
        COUNTROWS ( same_end ) > 1
            && [Start] = max_start
            && [Id] = min_id,
        [End] + TIME ( 0, 0, 1 ),
        [End]
    )
```

I have also updated the measure accordingly:

```
Man Hours = 
SUMX(
    SUMMARIZE(Logins, Logins[Name], "x",
        var l = Logins
        return CONVERT(
            SUMX(
                FILTER(Logins, 
                    var t = [Fudge_end]
                    var i = [Id]
                    return COUNTROWS(FILTER(Logins,  [Fudge_start] <= t && t <= [Fudge_end] )) == 1
                ), [End]
            ) -
            SUMX( 
                 FILTER(Logins,
                        var t = [Fudge_start]
                        var i = [Id]
                        return COUNTROWS(FILTER(Logins,  [Fudge_start] <= t && t <= [Fudge_end] )) == 1
                ), [Start]
            ), DOUBLE
        )
    ), [x]
) * 24
```

Result:
[image]